# Audio threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

I have a seperate thread for audio in my application because it sounded like a good idea at the time but now I am conserned at how other threads will comunicate with the audio thread.

```
audioThread() {

while(!isCloseRequested) {

If(audio.dogSoundRequested) {

audio.playDogSound();
        }
    }
}

otherThread() {

Audio.dogSoundRequested();

}
```

Would this be an efficient way to thread audio or do you see issues with this setup?

Comment: I'm unclear precisely what `playDogSound()` does here. Does it initiate playing a sound, generate the audio, or is a render handler? What is this program supposed to do?

Comment: @Marko that is a dummy function and is irelavent

Comment: Is it intended to run serially? e.g. only play one sound at once?

Comment: @Marko wow I had already for saw that issue and was pondering a solution so if you can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: Could I have an array of booleans so that I can play multiple sounds at the same time. Ex. If(dogSoundRequested[x]) with dogSoundRequested[0] returning false every time dogSoundRequested[10] returns true if you get what I am saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at stake here seems to be

1: how to make `audio.dogSoundRequested` and `isCloseRequested` thread-safe.

2: `audioThread` is busy-waiting (e.g. spinning infinitely until `audio.dogSoundRequested` becomes `true`.

As others have suggested, you could use a mutex to protect both variables, but this is overkill - additionally, it's generally good form in audio code not to use blocking sychronisation in order to avoid issues with [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion).

Instead, assuming you're using C++11 or C++14, you could use an atomic variable, whcih are lightweight and don't (in most implementations) block:

```
#include <atomic>

...

std::atomic<bool> dogSoundRequested{false};
std::atomic<bool> isCloseRequested{false};
```

Reads and writes to the std::atomic have the same contract as for built-in types, but will generate code that ensures the read and write are atomic with respect to other threads, and that the results are synchronised with other CPUs.

In the case of `audio.dogSoundRequested` you want both of these effects, and in the case of `isCloseRequested`, that the result is immediately visible on other CPU.

To solve the busy-waiting issue,  use a condition variable to awake `audioThread` when there's something to do:

```
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

audioThread() 
{
    while(!isCloseRequested) 
    {
        m.lock();
        cv.wait(m);

        // wait() returns with the mutex still held.
        m.unlock();
        if(audio.dogSoundRequested) 
        {
            audio.playDogSound();
        }
    }
}


void dogSoundRequested()
{
    dogSoundRequested = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the use of mutex, here is a simple setup for multiple threads

```
//  g++ -o multi_threading  -pthread -std=c++11 multi_threading.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <exception>
#include <mutex>
#include <climits>  // min max of short int

void launch_consumer() {

    std::cout << "launch_consumer" << std::endl;

}   //  launch_consumer

void launch_producer(std::string chosen_file) {

    std::cout << "launch_producer " << chosen_file << std::endl;

}   //  launch_producer

// -----------


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string chosen_file = "audio_file.wav";

    std::thread t1(launch_producer, chosen_file);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds( 100));

    std::thread t2(launch_consumer);

    // -------------------------

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicate the code with mutexes and condition variables, consider making a thread-safe FIFO.  In this case, one that could have multiple writers and one consumer.  Other threads of the application are the writers to this FIFO, the `audioThread()` is the consumer.

```
// NOP = no operation

enum AudioTask {NOP, QUIT, PLAY_DOG, ...};

class Fifo
{
    public:
    bool can_push() const;   // is it full?
    void push(AudioTask t);  // safely writes to the FIFO
    AudioTask pop();         // safely reads from the FIFO, if empty NOP
};
```

Now the `audioThread()` is a bit cleaner, assuming `fifo` and `audio` are application class members:

```
void audioThread()
{
    bool running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        auto task = fifo.pop();

        switch(task)
        {
            case NOP: std::this_thread::yield(); break;
            case QUIT: running = false; break;
            case PLAY_DOG: audio.playDogSound(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the calling code only needs to push tasks into the FIFO:

```
void request_dog_sound()
{
    fifo.push(PLAY_DOG);
}

void stop_audio_thread()
{
    fifo.push(QUIT);
    audio_thread.join();
}
```

This puts the details of the thread-safe synchronization inside the Fifo class, keeping the rest of the application cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to be sure that no other thread touches the `playDogSound()` function, use a mutex lock to lock the resource.

```
std::mutex mtx;

audioThread() {
    while(!isCloseRequested) {
        if (audio.dogSoundRequested) {
            mtx.lock();
            audio.playDogSound();
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well as far as locks are conserned I know openmp, which I'm using, has its own functions but thanks!

Comment: Your mutex is guarding nothing at all. Wrapping a function call in a mutex does not prevent another thread from calling it.